# Double Common Table Expression does not work in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

CTE does not work in SQL Server.
**This is the code:**

```
with t2 as 
(with t1 as
(select year(orderdate) as 'year',datename(mm,orderdate) as 'month',soh.TerritoryID,month(orderdate) as month_num,
sum(totaldue) as TotalAmount
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
group by year(orderdate),datename(mm,orderdate),month(orderdate),soh.TerritoryID)
select year,month,concat(st.Name,' ',st.CountryRegionCode) as Region,TotalAmount
from t1
join sales.SalesTerritory st on t1.TerritoryID=st.TerritoryID
order by year,month_num,TotalAmount desc)
select *
from t2
```

**I get this error:**
*If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.*

I still get the error if I put ; before the first CTE

As I remember, this was not an issue in MySQL.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't define a CTE inside another one. It's `WITH CTE1 AS (...), CTE2 AS (...) CTE3 AS (...) SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE...` See the [example Use multiple CTE definitions in a single query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-use-multiple-cte-definitions-in-a-single-query) from the documentation.

Comment: ... and just to complete the answer and a comment you've got already. Here is what official docs says "Specifying more than one WITH clause in a CTE isn't allowed. For example, if a CTE_query_definition contains a subquery, that subquery can't contain a nested WITH clause that defines another CTE."

Comment: *"I still get the error if I put ; before the first CTE"* As a side note, you don't put a semicolon (`;`) *before* the first `WITH`, you put a semicolon at the end of **every** statement. A CTE requires that the **previous** statement is properly terminated, not that the statement is properly "begun".

Answer (score 2):

```
with t1 as
(
  select year(orderdate) as 'year',
  datename(mm,orderdate) as 'month',
  soh.TerritoryID,
  month(orderdate) as month_num,
 sum(totaldue) as TotalAmount
 from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
 group by year(orderdate),datename(mm,orderdate),month(orderdate),soh.TerritoryID
),
t2 as
(
  select year,month,concat(st.Name,' ',st.CountryRegionCode) as Region,
      TotalAmount
  from t1
  join sales.SalesTerritory st on t1.TerritoryID=st.TerritoryID
)
select *
from t2
order by year,month,TotalAmount desc
```

I guess, you need something like this